# pymongo typeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument

Tags: python, sql-server, json, mongodb, pymongo

I was trying to migrate data from SQL Server to MongoDB but was getting below type error in the last phase while importing data to MongoDB.

```
mongoImp = dbo.insert_many(jArray)
  File "/home/lrsa/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 710, in insert_many
    blk.ops = [doc for doc in gen()]
  File "/home/lrsa/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 702, in gen
    common.validate_is_document_type("document", document)
  File "/home/lrsa/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/common.py", line 407, in validate_is_document_type
    "collections.MutableMapping" % (option,))
TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping
```

I have also checked the `type(jArray)` which is a `str`. Tried with converting the data type to `list` as well but could not succeed.

My Code:

```
import pyodbc
import json
import collections
import pymongo
from bson import json_util

odbcArray = []
mongoConStr = '192.168.10.107:36006'
sqlConStr = 'DRIVER={MSSQL-NC1311};SERVER=tcp:192.168.10.103,57967;DATABASE=AdventureWorks;UID=testuser;PWD=testuser'
mongoConnect = pymongo.MongoClient(mongoConStr)
sqlConnect = pyodbc.connect(sqlConStr)

dbo = mongoConnect.eaedw.sqlData
dbDocs = dbo.find()
sqlCur = sqlConnect.cursor()
sqlCur.execute("""
            SELECT TOP 2 BusinessEntityID,Title, Demographics, rowguid, ModifiedDate
            FROM Person.Person
            """)

tuples = sqlCur.fetchall()

for tuple in tuples:
    doc = collections.OrderedDict()
    doc['id'] = tuple.BusinessEntityID
    doc['title'] = tuple.Title
    doc['dgrap'] = tuple.Demographics
    doc['rowi'] = tuple.rowguid
    doc['mtime'] = tuple.ModifiedDate
    odbcArray.append(doc)

jArray = json.dumps(odbcArray, default=json_util.default)
mongoImp = dbo.insert_many(jArray)

mongoConnect.close()
sqlConnect.close()
```

Comment: try without dumping the dict.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out this [bulk insert example](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#bulk-inserts) from MongoDB:s webpage. Skip the `json.dumps` call (which turns your array of documents into a json formatted string) and insert `odbcArray` directly:

```
mongoImp = dbo.insert_many(odbcArray)
```

Comment: Actually, Since `odbcArray` is not in a JSON format and thought would not work. So, I have explicitly converted into jsonArray. Anyways, thanks for the help it was working like a charm

Comment: I had similar issue where I wrote a big JSON to S3, then read it back in later and sent it to Mongo, after doing "dict_obj = json.loads(str_value)".  I forgot it was multiple documents, so I just changed insert_one to insert_many to fix the issue.

Comment: The link has changed to this:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.insert/

Comment: Link has changed:
https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#bulk-inserts